# Check whether an element has a successor in java Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm

I am trying to check whether an element of array has a successor.in other words, make the Ascending sublist to `0` and the rest to `1`. the first element of the `inputArray` should be ignored

if yes then the both element should be `0` if not then `1`. For example: for the input

```
int[] arr = {1,8,1,9,10};
```

the output should be `[1,1,1,0,0]`

another example: for the input   `int[] arr = {1,2,3,9,100};` should the output be: `[1,0,0,1,1]`

This is my try, but it does not work as expected. Where am i making failur?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 8, 1, 9, 10 };

        int[] listOutput;
        for (int i = 1; i<arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] - arr[i + 1] == -1) {
                arr[i] = 0;
                arr[i + 1] = 0;
            } else {
                arr[i] = 1;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not defined well, what should be the output for `[1, 2, 3, 5]`? should `3` become `0` because `2` has a successor, or should it become `1`, because `5` is not its successor? What should `5` become?

Comment: the output should be  `[1,0,0,1]` so the first element shoud be ignored and `3` is successor for 2 then the both should be `0` and 5 is not successor for 3 then `5` should be `1`

Comment: should the first element remain unchanged? even though `1` is successor for `2` only `2` should be set to `0` and not both?

Comment: yes the first element remain unchanged

Comment: Does the solution in my answer solve your problem accordingly?

Comment: Ok, wait. I think it does not work for the output you gave to `[1,2,3,5]`. Could you please explain why `3` should become `0` and not `1`? It could be `0` because it's successor to `2`, but it could also be `1` because `5` is not its successor. Why choose `0`? Is setting `0` always preferred?

Comment: `3` is the succ of `2` then both should be `0` and `5` is not succ from `3` then 5 should `1` in case of `[1,2,3,40,41]` then the output should be `[1,0,0,0,0]` could you please change your code accordingly?

Comment: In other words. Make the Ascending sublist of the list to 0 and the rest to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 8, 1, 9, 10 };

    // assume arr.length >= 2
    boolean asc = arr[1] - arr[0] == 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] == 1) {
            arr[i] = 0;
            asc = true;
        } else {
            if (asc) {
                asc = false;
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
            else {
                arr[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    arr[arr.length - 1] = asc ? 0 : 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

This will replace each ascending (by 1) sublist of size greater than 1 with 0s, and will replace each remaining element with 1 (besides the first element which remains unchanged).

Comment: In other words. Make the Ascending sublist of the list to 0 and the rest to 1

Comment: @Catalina ok, that's a clear description now. With just one addition: leave the first element unchanged?

Comment: leave the first element unchanged--> yes

Comment: @Catalina I made one more update, to remove the funny `backup` approach.

Comment: How can i change the `arr[arr.length - 1] = asc ? 0 : 1;` in case of `ArrayList`? the `arr.get(path.size() - 1) = asc ? arr.set(path.size() - 1, 0) : arr.set(path.size() - 1, 1);
` does not work

Comment: @Catalina `ArrayList` has a separate `set` method to change the value of a cell.

Comment: Coud you please provide a solution in case of `ArrayList` ?

Comment: @Catalina just replace each `arr[X] = Y` with `arr.set(X, Y)`. E.g. `arr.set(arr.size() - 1, asc ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: I have last question please. How can i store the both number as tuple in that array? for example: `[ 1, 8, 1, 9, 10]`  ---> `[1,(8,1),(1,1),(1,1),(9,0),(10,0)]` could you please change your code accordingly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209876/discussion-between-catalina-and-ciamej).

Answer (score 0):

You're looping the array from `1` instead of from `0`.

Comment: Yes the first element should be ignored